# In MDX, the price rank of a given number is 0

Tags: mdx, pivot-table, olap-cube

I have an OLAP cube containing the type price sum for each of number.

Using MDX, how can I output the rank of a given number?

Result should be as follows:

[image]

Heare is the MDX query, but all rank values are 0. What is wrong in query?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Rank Sum of price] AS
   RANK([NUM_1].[All Numbers].CURRENTMEMBER
   ,[NUM_1].[All Numbers]
   ,[Measures].[Sum of price])

SELECT 
 {
  [Measures].[Sum of price] 
, [Measures].[Rank Sum of price]
 }
 ON COLUMNS,

  [NUM_1].[All Numbers]
 ON ROWS 
 FROM schema1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do your ordering in a custom set before hitting the rank function:

```
WITH 
  SET OrderedNums AS 
    Order
    (
      [NUM_1].[All Numbers].[All Numbers].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Sum of price]
     ,BDESC
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Rank Sum of price] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [NUM_1].[All Numbers].CurrentMember
     ,OrderedNums
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Sum of price]
   ,[Measures].[Rank Sum of price]
  } ON 0
 ,[NUM_1].[All Numbers].[All Numbers].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM schema1;
```